# Qthread,adding function to qthread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

I have a class like that

```
class Class1 : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    void a();
    void b();
    ...........

void Class1:a()
{
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        b();//I want here to make parallel 

           //and wait here all threads are done


}
```

how can I use qhthread here,I ve looked to tutorials they all are just for classes not for a function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to run a function on a separate thread, you can use [`QtConcurrent`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtconcurrent.html) like this:

```
QtConcurrent::run(this, &Class1::b);
```

**Edit:** You can use [`QFutureSynchronizer`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qfuturesynchronizer.html) to wait for all threads, don't forget to allocate all threads using `QThreadPool::globalInstance()->setMaxThreadCount()`.

**Edit 2:** You can use `synchronizer.futures()` to acess all threads return values.

Example:

```
QThreadPool::globalInstance()->setMaxThreadCount(10);
QFutureSynchronizer<int> synchronizer;
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    synchronizer.addFuture(QtConcurrent::run(this, &Class1::b));
synchronizer.waitForFinished();
foreach(QFuture<int> thread, synchronizer.futures())
    qDebug() << thread.result(); //Get the return value of each thread.
```

Comment: thank you and also how function(a) can wait until all treads are done.

Comment: thank you @ user2014561 I am asking so much but last question is if the b return a value how can we get it(for instance :int b())

Comment: Is the setMaxThreadCount function really needed, what if it is difficult to estimate the number of threads needed?

Comment: @ejectamenta: It depends, if you already have the number of threads you want to use in parallel available in thread pool, then you don't need re-allocate them. Do this just to make sure. If you're not sure how many pooled threads you'll use, you can alocate one more pooled thread before start each thread like this: `int maxthread = QThreadPool::globalInstance()->maxThreadCount() + 1; QThreadPool::globalInstance()->setMaxThreadCount(maxthread);`